# Conditions in for loop

Tags: python, loops, pandas, for-loop, while-loop

Using  pandas data frame in python:

I am trying to get the following data from a data frame and cant fix my loop to get the proper result.

A small sample of the data set:

```
BERTH     FROM_BERTH       BI
29          H2             0
29          09             0
29          J5             0
C5          NaN            1
J4          NaN            1
J2          NaN            1
```

Here is part of the dataset ( the relevant columns i need to use) and here is what i want the output to look like :

```
29, H2, 09, J5, C5, J4, J2
```

that is: if BI is 0 i want the value from BERTH and then the values of FROM_BERTH till BI becomes 1, and then goes back to giving me the BERTH ( untill BI becomes 1 again, so on ans so forth ).

Here are the following codes i have tried and their results :

```
test_berth2 = []

for i in range(0,6):
    if df3_test.loc[i,'BI'] == 0 & df3_test.iloc[i,21] != df3.iloc[i-1,21]:
        test_berth2.append(df3_test.loc[i,'BERTH'])
        test_berth2.append(df3_test.loc[i,'FROM_BERTH'])
    elif df3_test.loc[i,'BI'] == 0 & df3_test.iloc[i,21] == df3.iloc[i+1,21]:         
        test_berth2.append(df3_test.loc[i,'FROM_BERTH'])

    else :
        test_berth2.append(df3_test.loc[i,'BERTH'])

test_berth2
```

result :

```
['29', 'H2', '29', '09', '29', 'J5', 'C5', 'J4', 'J2']
```

Loop 2 :

```
for i in range(0,6):
    if df3_test.iloc[i,21] == 0:
        print (df3_test.loc[i,'BERTH'])
        while df3_test.iloc[i,21] == 0:
            print (df3_test.loc[i,'FROM_BERTH'])
            i = i+1
    else:
        print (df3_test.loc[i,'BERTH'],'1')
```

result :

```
29, H2, 09, J5, 29, 09, J5, 29, J5, C5 1, J4 1, J2 1
```

PS :the iloc to column 21 is 'BI' btw

Comment: In your first “for” loop, in the if/elif conditions, make sure that the ampersands are doing what you want them to do. I suspect that you want the boolean (“and”) rather than the bitwise (“&”) operator.

Comment: Never tried that, thank you for the suggestion will give it a go. Hopefully that will work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, one way you do this is using Pandas groupby:

```
df.groupby(df.BI.cumsum())\
  .apply(lambda x: [x['BERTH'].iloc[0]]+x['FROM_BERTH'].dropna().tolist())\
  .sum()
```

Output:

```
['29', 'H2', '09', 'J5', 'C5', 'J4', 'J2']
```

Note: `cumsum` is the trick.  It will allow the creation of a group based on zero in BI and creates a group of 1 records for the BI equal to anything non-zero.  Then, we get the first value from BERTH and all the FROM_BERTH values in that group.

## Edit for question in comment:

```
df.groupby(df.BI.cumsum())\
  .apply(lambda x: x['FROM_BERTH'].dropna().tolist()+[x['BERTH'].iloc[0]])\
  .sum()
```

Output:

```
['H2', '09', 'J5', '29', 'C5', 'J4', 'J2']
```

Comment: Thank you, will try it out asap!

Comment: It works! 1 more question though, how would i edit this to make it have the result:  [ 'H2', '09', 'J5', '29', 'C5', 'J4', 'J2']. that is have the 29 after instead of before.

Comment: `df.groupby(df.BI.cumsum())\
  .apply(lambda x: x['FROM_BERTH'].dropna().tolist()+[x['BERTH'].iloc[0]])\
  .sum()`

Comment: @AasheetKumar Glad that worked.  See edit in solution to address your question here.